# Eclipse RCP and RAP customizable table control

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I am looking for a table control that is customizable and works both on RCP and RAP, single source.

By customizable I mean this:

- a cell from this table can also be splitted again in rows and columns. Or should be possible for the cell renderer to draw this cell to look like another table
- it should be possible to have a group of columns fixed to the left side (but not necessary, because I think some workaround would be possible)
- should be possible to have columngroups

Maybe some of you can help me with such a control, maybe some names so I can do some research on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAP 3.0 (to be released June 2015 with Eclipse Mars) [contains an implementation](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/noteworthy/3.0/?build=M2) of the [Nebula Grid](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php). This widget supports column groups.

RAP Trees and Tables support a number of columns fixed to the left edge via `setData(RWT.FIXED_COLUMS, Boolean.TRUE)`. This feature is not yet available for Grid, but chances are it can be added.

Splitting cells is not yet supported in RAP, however, using the support for HTML markup it could probably be simulated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am currently testing the nebula grid on RAP. hopefully it will help me.

Comment: I'll mark this as the right answer, because there is no such control for RAP. The only alternative is customize the table on RAP from HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the eclipse nebula project. There is a Grid widget which could meet your needs